# Using POST to send CSV file

Tags: php, http, csv

This maybe the completely wrong method but I am trying to understand how to send a `CSV` file to a php page which will then read it. I have tried using an `HTTP POST` but it fails saying  **Undefined index: csv1**. This is what I have so far:

Form on html page:

```
<form action="http://xxx/readcsv.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input name="csv1" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

readcsv.php

```
...
if ($_FILES[$_POST['csv1']][size] > 0) { 
$file = $_FILES[$_POST['csv1']][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 


  while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) 
  { 

    if ($data[0]) 
    { 
     do stuff with the content
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Instead of `$_FILES[$_POST['csv1']]`, you should use `$_FILES['csv1']`

Comment: But how to define csv1? If I put $csv1=$_POST['csv1']; I still get an index error.

Comment: **Never** use `$_POST['csv1']`. It simply does not exist. Use `$_FILES['csv1']` instead.

Comment: It works - thanks. Still a little confused as to how the php page knows what csv1 is without defining it in some way or receiving the POST.

Comment: I don't exactly know how it works. But if you have a file, it is always in `$_FILES` :) I guess files are transmitted in another way than simple texts.